# PWM supplying led breaks down at near to zero threshold

Tags: led, interrupt, pwm

I use timer1, mode 8, on both pin 9 and 10 at 1 kHz my PWM signal breaks down when I turn the potentiometer just above where I set the zero at, no matter where I set the zero at.  I power the Arduino atmega328p with Vin and disconnect from the PC.  I have potentiometer to A0 and pin out 9 or 10 connected to the oscilloscope.  I have code and picture below.

The problem with my code is that I can't get TCNT1 or TCNT2 to start where I set it anywhere else but zero.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
//#include <SPI.h>
//ISR(TIM1_COMPA);
//ISR(TIM1_CAPT);

int analogInPin = PC0;
int analogOutPin9 = PB1;
int analogOutPin10 = PB2;
int analogOutPin3 = PD3;
int analogOutPin11 = PB3;
//int analogInPin = A0;
//int analogOutPin9 = 9;
//int analogOutPin10 = 10;

int sensorValueTimer1;
int sensorValueTimer2;

void sens(int &sensorValueTimer1, int &sensorValueTimer2){
   sensorValueTimer1 = (((long)analogRead(analogInPin)*1000)/1023);
   if (sensorValueTimer1 < 35){  //to stop flickering at low end
     sensorValueTimer1 = 0;
     }
        sensorValueTimer2 = (((long)analogRead(analogInPin)*255)/1023);
   if (sensorValueTimer2 < 0){  //to stop flickering at low end
     sensorValueTimer2 = 0;
     }
}

void updateOCRnx(){
  sens(sensorValueTimer1,sensorValueTimer2);
  int x = sensorValueTimer1;
  int y = sensorValueTimer2;
  OCR1A = x;
  OCR1B = x;
  OCR2A = y;
  OCR2B = y;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //===============mode 5 pin 3,11==================//
  /*
  //TCCR2A = 0;
  //TCCR2B = 0;
  TCCR2A |= (1<<COM2A1);
  TCCR2A |= (1<<COM2A0);
  TCCR2A |= (1<<COM2B1);
  TCCR2A |= (1<<COM2B0);
  TCCR2A |= (1<<WGM21);
  TCCR2A |= (1<<WGM20);
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<WGM22);
  TCCR2B &= ~(1<<CS22);
  TCCR2B |= (1<<CS21);
  TCCR2B |= (1<<CS20);

  //TIMSK2 |= (1<<OCIE2A);
  //TIMSK2 |= (1<<OCIE2B);
  //TIMSK2 |= (1<<TOIE2);
  //ASSR &= ~(1<<TCN2UB);
  //TIFR2 |= (1<<OCF2A);
  //TIFR2 |= (1<<TOV2);


  TCNT2 = 100;
 */
  //====================mode 5 pin 3,11=====================//
  //=====================mode 8 pin 9,10=====================//
  //TCCR1A = 0;

  TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A1);
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1A0);
  TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1B1);
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<COM1B0);
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM11);
  TCCR1A &= ~(1<<WGM10);
  TCCR1B |= (1<<WGM13);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1<<WGM12);
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1<<CS12);
  TCCR1B &= ~(1<<CS10); 


  //TCCR1B |= (1<<ICES1);

  //TCCR1C |= (FOC1A);
  //TCCR1C |= (FOC1B);

  ICR1=1000;  //1.333KH
  TCNT1=0;

  //TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1);
  //TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A);
  //TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1B);
  //TIMSK1 |= (1<<ICIE1);
  //TIFR1 |= (1<<TOV1);
  //TIFR1 |= (1<<OCF1A);
  //TIFR1 |= (1<<OCF1B); 

  //EIMSK |= (1<<INT1);
  //EIFR |= (1<<INTF1); 
  //EICRA &= ~(1<<ISC11);
  //EICRA &= ~(1<<ISC10);

  //PCMSK0 |= (1<<PCINT2);
  //PCICR |= (1<<PCIE0); //pin change interrupt 0 is enabled
  //PCIFR |= (1<<PCIF1); // triggers an interrupt request
  //=======================mode 8 pin 9,10=======================//

  sei();

  //pinMode(analogOutPin9,OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(10, INPUT);
  //pinMode(analogInPin, INPUT);

  //char data;

  DDRB |= (1<<analogInPin);
  DDRB |= (1<<analogOutPin9);
  DDRB |= (1<<analogOutPin10);
  DDRB |= (1<<analogOutPin11);
  DDRB |= (1<<analogOutPin3);
  //DDRB |= (1<<PB5);
  //DDRB &= ~(1<<PB4);

  //SPSR |= (1<<SPIF); 

  //SPCR |= (1<<SPE);
  //SPCR |= (1<<MSTR);
  //SPSR &= ~(SPR1);
  //SPCR |= (1<<SPR0);
  //SPSR |= (1<<SPI2X);  

  //SPDR = data;

}


void loop() { 
  updateOCRnx();
  Serial.println(TCNT1);
  //delay(100); 
  //int sensorValue = (((long)analogRead(analogInPin)*1000)/1023);
  //int sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  //analogWrite(analogOutPin9, sensorValue/4);
  //analogWrite(analogOutPin10, sensorValue/4);
  //Serial.println(analogOutPin9);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is your oscilloscope `Trigger Mode` set to? `Auto` or `Normal`?

Comment: The trigger mode was set to auto, I set it to normal, I still see the square wave expand out a little bit for about  1/10 a second and repeats every half a second.  I see the same thing on the light fixture with CREE XPE2 LED.  It flickers about the same as the oscilloscope flickers when I have my MCIGICM 10K Ohm potentiometer at very near to where I set zero at.  My corals and my eyes are thank full for a direction.

Answer (score -1):

The analogread pin is unstable. This fixed it,ResponsiveAnalogRead, [from github](https://github.com/dxinteractive/ResponsiveAnalogRead)

Comment: That's a vague explanation and IMHO not evident